# Chart doesn't make space for empty columns

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am creating a chart for the visualization of weekly stats. That means that I need a 7 columns chart and, if the data is not available, leave an empty space on the corresponding column.
I am having a lot of troubles because I haven't found a proper guide for charting in WPF (if you have any feel free to share)

This is my chart:

```
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

<charting:Chart Name="LastWeekChart" Grid.Row="0"  Width="895" Height ="250"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
    <charting:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</charting:Chart>
```

And this is the code behind:

```
public static List<SingleBar> LastWeek = new List<SingleBar>();
class SingleBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public SingleBar()
    {
        this.Name = "";
        this.Value = 0;
    }
    public SingleBar(string name, double value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

And this is how I fill the chart if there are missing data:

```
if (LastWeek.Count() < 7)
for (int i = LastWeek.Count(); i < 7; i++)
    LastWeek.Insert(0, new SingleBar());
```

So if there are less than 7 data, it inserts empty data at the beginning.
Now I saw that on the code the bars are added, but on the graph only one empty bar is displayed, no matter how many empty bars I added. Anyone can help me?

EDIT: To reproduce it, try something like this:

```
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar());
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar());
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar());
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar());
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar("Friday",50));
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar("Saturday", 75));
LastWeek.Add(new SingleBar("Sunday",60));
LastWeekChart.DataContext = LastWeek;
```

Comment: Your problem is unreproducible from your code.

Comment: I read logs from an external device, so you can't reproduce it. Try the code I added now, it creates the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant, but I have used Oxyplot in the past and find it much easier to work with (read as: wpf tool kit is a pain).

Here's an example using oxyplot with some empty bars in the start of each series:

[image]

You can find their examples [here](http://www.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/) . Just click the one you like ,and you can view the code (on the bottom you have a code/plot tab).

Here's the code for screetshot in case you wonder:

Xaml:

```
  <Window x:Class="wpfoxyempty.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.codeplex.com"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
          Name="OxyDemo"
          >
      <Grid>
          <oxy:Plot Model="{Binding ElementName=OxyDemo, Path=OutputChart}" 
                    Margin="5" />

      </Grid>
  </Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()

    {
        OutputChart = new PlotModel();
        SetUpModel(OutputChart);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetUpModel(PlotModel plotModel)
    {

        var plotModel1 = new PlotModel();
        plotModel1.LegendBorderThickness = 0;
        plotModel1.LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal;
        plotModel1.LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside;
        plotModel1.LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter;
        plotModel1.Title = "No axes defined";

        var linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis();
        linearAxis1.MinimumPadding = 0;
        linearAxis1.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);

        var categoryAxis1 = new CategoryAxis();
        categoryAxis1.MinorStep = 1;
        categoryAxis1.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("1");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("2");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("3");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("4"); 
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("5");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("6");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("7");
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(categoryAxis1);

        var barSeries1 = new BarSeries();
        barSeries1.StrokeThickness = 1;
        barSeries1.Title = "Series 1";
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(137, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(18, -1));
        barSeries1.Items.Add(new BarItem(40, -1));
        plotModel1.Series.Add(barSeries1);

        var barSeries2 = new BarSeries();
        barSeries2.StrokeThickness = 1;
        barSeries2.Title = "Series 2";
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(0, -1));
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(30, -1));
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(40, -1)); 
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(12, -1));
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(68, -1));
        barSeries2.Items.Add(new BarItem(8, -1));
        plotModel1.Series.Add(barSeries2);

        OutputChart = plotModel1;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the plot (chart) we'll display
    /// </summary>
    public PlotModel OutputChart
    {
        get { return _outputChart; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _outputChart)) return;
            _outputChart = value;

        }
    }
    private PlotModel _outputChart;

}
```

Comment: Look nice; to be honest I saw Oxyplot first, but then I decided to go for WPF toolkit because it looked simpler. Unfortunately, I discovered a lot of limitation while using it, so I might reconsider...

Comment: it takes me a couple of hours to get my feet after a long time of not using it, but when I first started hunting for graphs, I tried WPF toolkit, and was highly disappointed. I've done some cool things with Oxyplot, and it's under development, and you can get help on their forums as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try it!